# Accessto DI object after request finished. asp .net core 2.1

Tags: api, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, lifecycle

I want to acces dbcontext DI object after request finished, e.g. do some background task atfet request complete and keep it short.

sample code:

```
await bunusInfoService.CheckBonus(user.Id, _appSettings.GregSysRegisterIP);
UserDto uss = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
return uss;
```

but call of bunusInfoService.CheckBonus without await.

it says:

Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

Comment: If you can share the relevant code, we will help troubleshot the issue better.

Comment: like this:   

await bunusInfoService.CheckBonus(user.Id, _appSettings.GregSysRegisterIP);


      UserDto uss = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(user);
      uss.Token = GenerateJWTToken(user.Id.ToString(), "User");
      uss.RefreshToken = currentAuth.RefreshToken;
      uss.RefreshTokenExpDate = currentAuth.RefreshTokenExpDate;
      uss.isSuccess = true;
      return uss;
    }

but call of bunusInfoService.CheckBonus without await